# Typescript: Chips are not visible in Textfield

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my project, there is a field that shows multiple address chips. Now I am facing a problem. When you copy and paste multiple address values into the field, it will not show in the field, but the value will be updated and displayed in the console:

[image]

[image]

But after that situation press any key (Not enter) which shows the values like this:

[image]

I want to avoid this delay. My requirement is to paste multiple values and then press "enter" key, the values will appear in the field.I tried to correct this situation but failed. Please give me some suggestions to solve this problem

```
import { faCircleQuestion, faXmark } from "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Chip, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { JSXElementConstructor, Key, ReactElement, ReactFragment, useRef, useState } from "react";
import validator from "validator";

import styles from "./index.module.scss";

type Props = {
  LabelName?: string;
  optional?: string;
  tooltip?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  className?: string;
  upload?: boolean;
  items?: any;
  setItem: (items: any) => void;
};
const TagActions = (props: Props) => {
  // const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  const {
    LabelName,
    optional,
    tooltip,
    placeholder,
    className,
    upload,
    items,
    setItem,
  } = props;

  const handleDelete = (item: any) => {
    const result = items.filter((i: any) => i !== item);
    setItem(result);
  };

  const handleItemEdit = (item: any) => {
    const result = items.filter((i: any) => i !== item);
    setItem(result);
    setValue(item);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (evt: any) => {
    if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      const test = value.trim();

      if (test && isValid(test)) {
        items.push(test);
        setValue("");
      }
    }
  };

  const isValid = (email: any) => {
    let error = null;

    if (isInList(email)) {
      error = `${email} has already been added.`;
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      setFlag(true);
    }

    if (error) {
      setError(error);

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  const isInList = (email: any) => {
    return items.includes(email);
  };

  const handleChange = (evt: any) => {
    setValue(evt.target.value);
  };

  const handlePaste = (evt: any) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
    const emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\\.-]+@[\w\d\\.-]+\.[\w\d\\.-]+/g);

    if (emails) {
      const toBeAdded = emails.filter((email: any) => !isInList(email));

      console.log("items inside", items);
      toBeAdded.map((i: any) => {
        items.push(i);
      });
      console.log("items after", items);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="formSection">
        {LabelName && (
          <div className={`control-label ${styles.label}`}>
            <label>
              <span className={styles.alignLeft}>
                <span className={styles.labelText}>{LabelName}</span>
              </span>
            </label>

            <span className={styles.alignRight}>
              {upload && (
                <label htmlFor="uploadCSV">
                  <span className={styles.upload}>Upload CSV</span>
                </label>
              )}

              {optional && <span className={styles.light}>Optional</span>}

              {tooltip && (
                <span className={styles.tooltip_ic} title={tooltip}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleQuestion} size="xs" />
                </span>
              )}
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
        <input
          type="file"
          accept=".csv"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          id="uploadCSV"
        />
        <div className={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextField
            className={` textfield-emailchip test ${className}`}
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: items.map(
                (
                  item:
                    | boolean
                    | Key
                    | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>
                    | ReactFragment
                    | null
                    | undefined
                    | any
                    | string
                ) => (
                  <Chip
                    className={
                      !validator.isEmail(item)
                        ? styles.chipTagError
                        : styles.chipTag
                    }
                    key={item}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    label={item}
                    onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
                    onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
                    deleteIcon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} size="xs" />}
                  />
                )
              ),
            }}
            ref={divRef}
            value={value}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            onPaste={(e) => handlePaste(e)}
          />
        </div>

        {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TagActions;
```

Comment: Well that is because in `handleKeyDown` you just expect there to be one email? You might want to split or atleast check for multiple emails by a delimeter such as `[,\s]`

Comment: Other email values cannot be typed when using \s

Comment: Well the idea is to not just `value.trim()` but also `value.split(/[,\s]+/)` this will create an array of all emails. you can then do `test.filter(isValid)` to get valid emails then append those emails to items.